# Add class to closest element of e.target

Tags: html, jquery, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a shake effect to a font-awesome icon whenever hovering over the hyperlink beside it.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="icon-hyperlink">
     <span>
          <i class="fas fa-phone p-2"></i>
     </span>

     <span>
          <a href="tel:XXXX XX XX XX">John: XXXX XX XX XX</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add the class fa-shake to the matching i with class "fas", and remove it when not hovering.

I'm not super well versed in jQuery, but I read a lot of the documentation and other stackoverflow articles getting this to work, to no avail.

My current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".icon-hyperlink a").hover(function(e) {
          e.target.closest(".fas").addClass("fa-shake");
     }, function(e) {
          e.target.closest(".fas").removeClass("fa-shake");     
     });
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addClass')

I also tried the following:

```
$(e.target.closest(".fas")).addClass("fa-shake");
```

That gives me no errors, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Why not add the _hover_ listener on the `.icon-hyperlink` element. Then you can simply use `$(this).find(".fas")`

Comment: The internal `spans` seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse up to a shared parent, then find the icon

```js
$(".icon-hyperlink a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).closest(".icon-hyperlink").find(".fas").addClass("fa-shake");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).closest(".icon-hyperlink").find(".fas").removeClass("fa-shake");
  }
);
```

---

As mentioned above, the `<span>` elements seem unnecessary and just complicate the matter.

Also, it's 2022 and you probably don't need jQuery.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches(".icon-hyperlink a")) {
    e.target
      .closest(".icon-hyperlink")
      .querySelector(".fas")
      ?.classList.add("fa-shake");
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches(".icon-hyperlink a")) {
    e.target
      .closest(".icon-hyperlink")
      .querySelector(".fas")
      ?.classList.remove("fa-shake");
  }
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much! Can you explain why I couldn't get it to work with e.target though?
I think there's something fundamental that I'm not understanding about that.

Comment: There's no difference between `this` and `e.target` in jQuery's event handlers. Your code didn't work because the icon isn't in the document hierarchy of the `<a>` tag

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks for the help and the alternative solution as well. It seems I have to brush up my HTML knowledge a bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.parents()` and `.find()` instead to select the `.fas` element you're trying to find.

Just ignore the html and css changes I made, they're only there to demonstrate the js. Instead of shaking, the `.fas` element turns red.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".icon-hyperlink a").hover(function(e) {
                $(e.target).parents(".icon-hyperlink").find(".fas").addClass("fa-shake");
        }, function(e) {
                $(e.target).parents(".icon-hyperlink").find(".fas").removeClass("fa-shake");     
        });

  });
```

```css
.fa-shake {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-hyperlink">
        <span>
                <i class="fas fa-phone p-2">Icon</i>
        </span>
        <span>
                <a href="tel:XXXX XX XX XX">John: XXXX XX XX XX</a>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. I think I was close then, but was trying something along the lines of $(e.target).parent().closest(".fas"). Possibly forgot to put the $() around e.target as well. It's been a while since I've used JQuery, I need to go through the documentation a bit more carefully whenever I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with no javascript and a little detective work of what FA uses behind the scenes.

```css
.phone::before{
  font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  content: "\f095";
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:900;
  color:black;
  margin-right:0.25em;  
}

.phone:hover::before{
  animation-name: fa-shake;
  animation-duration: var(--fa-animation-duration,1s);
  animation-iteration-count: var(--fa-animation-iteration-count,infinite);
  animation-timing-function: var(--fa-animation-timing,linear);
  animation-delay: var(--fa-animation-delay,0s);
  animation-direction: var(--fa-animation-direction,normal);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<div class="icon-hyperlink">
  <a href="tel:XXXX XX XX XX" class="phone">John: XXXX XX XX XX</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Was trying to think of a CSS-only solution but thought OP might need SASS or something similar to incorporate FA. This is much simpler

Comment: @Phil the main drawback is stepping away from the standard FA implementation. For me, that's not a big deal as I'm not a fan of the standard implementation.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of `.icon-hyperlink a:hover + .fas { shakeMixin() }` (I don't use FA so that's a very rough guess)